# xrandr set a new virtual monitor: X Error of failed request

Tags: linux, xorg, x-server, xrandr

I'm trying to set a new virtual monitor with `xrandr` and I get the following errors:

```
$xrandr --setmonitor VIRTUAL1 1366/256x768/144+0+1080 none

X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  43 ()
  Value in failed request:  0x203
  Serial number of failed request:  38
  Current serial number in output stream:  39
```

Explaining the problem visually cos I may have missunderstood a point

```
$xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected 1280x800+1920+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
HDMI-2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm

  +------------+----------+-------------------------+ ----> Screen 0
  |            |          |                         |
  |  HDMI-2    | eDP-1    |                         |
  |------------+-------+--+                         |
  |            |       |                            |    DP-1 (unallocated)
  |            | HDMI-1|                            |
  |            +-------+                            |
  |                                                 |
  |                                                 |
  |                                                 |
  |               SPACE AVAILABLE                   |
  |                                                 |
  |                                                 |
  |                                                 |
  |                                                 |
  |                                                 |
  |                                                 |
  +-------------------------------------------------+

I wanna create a new virtual monitor below HDMI-2

                 +------------+----------+-------------------------+
                 |            |          |                         |
                 |            |          |                         |
        +--------X-------+----+-------+--+                         |
        |        | HERE  |    |       |                            |
     offset      |-------+    |       |                            |
    coordinates  |            +-------+                            |
    in px        |                                                 |
                 |                                                 |
                 |                                                 |
                 |                                                 |
                 |                                                 |
                 |                                                 |
                 |                                                 |
                 |                                                 |
                 |                                                 |
                 |                                                 |
                 +-------------------------------------------------+
```

What am I doing wrong? , the Screen 0 still have a lot of space available I should theoretically be able to set a new monitor on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write eDP-1 instead of screen 0.